# Converting string to date in numpy unpack

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, data-science, urllib

I'm learning how to extract data from links and then proceeding to graph them.

For this tutorial, I was using the yahoo dataset of a stock.

The code is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter


def graph_data(stock):
    stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    stock_data = []
    split_source=source_code.split('\n')

    print(len(split_source))

    for line in split_source:
        split_line=line.split(',')
        if (len(split_line)==7):
            stock_data.append(line)


    date,openn,closep,highp,lowp,openp,volume=np.loadtxt(stock_data,delimiter=',',unpack=True,converters={0:bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

    plt.plot_date(date,closep)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Graph')
    plt.show()

graph_data('TSLA')
```

The whole code is pretty easy to understand except the part of converting the string datatype into date format using bytesupdate2num function.

Is there an easier way to convert strings extracted from reading a URL into date format during numpy extraction or is there another method I can use.

Thank you

Comment: This is using a `matplotlib` string to date converter.  `matplotlib` has had this custom date code long before `numpy` added its `np.datetime64`.  Without a sample csv file I couldn't say whether `numpy` can do the conversion without the `matplotlib` help, especially since the target is a plot function.

Answer (score 0):

With a guess as to the csv format, I can use the `numpy` 'native' datetime dtype:

```
In [183]: txt = ['2020-10-23 1 2.3']*3                                                                               
In [184]: txt                                                                                                        
Out[184]: ['2020-10-23 1 2.3', '2020-10-23 1 2.3', '2020-10-23 1 2.3']
```

If I let `genfromtxt` do its own `dtype` conversions:

```
In [187]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, encoding=None)                                                              
Out[187]: 
array([('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3), ('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3),
       ('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

the date column is rendered as a string.

If I specify a `datetime64` format:

```
In [188]: np.array('2020-10-23', dtype='datetime64[D]')                                                              
Out[188]: array('2020-10-23', dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [189]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=['datetime64[D]',int,float], encoding=None)                                       
Out[189]: 
array([('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3), ('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3),
       ('2020-10-23', 1, 2.3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[D]'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

This date appears to work in `plt`

```
In [190]: plt.plot_date(_['f0'], _['f1'])
```

I used `genfromtxt` because I'm more familiar with its ability to handle dtypes.