# Convert string to matplotlib date for plotting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I've been trying to convert string date into a format that can be plotted on a graph.

The code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

def graph_data():

    fig=plt.figure()
    ax1=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))

    stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    stock_data = []
    split_source=source_code.split('\n')

    print(len(split_source))

    for line in split_source[1:]:
        stock_data.append(line)


    date,openn,closep,highp,lowp,openp,volume=np.loadtxt(stock_data,delimiter=',',unpack=True)

    x = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') for d in date]

    ax1.plot_date(x,closep,'-',linewidth=0.1)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Graph')
    plt.show()

graph_data()
```

Any method of conversion just gives the same error

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-07-26'**

What method can I use to convert the string into date that can be plotted

Comment: Wait, you have a working code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718336/converting-string-to-date-in-numpy-unpack), so simply use it!

Answer (score 0):

Ther's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is with the data.
If you look at the data, you will find that from date to volume features your data is a string like this :
data = '2017-07-26,153.3500,153.9300,153.0600,153.5000,153.5000,12778195.00'.
That is the representation of a string.
So you need to do some preprocessing first. There may be various methods to do so.
I found this method helpful to me:

First, you have to remove the commas in data and replace them with spaces and then use the split function to convert data into a split format.

So, you need to make these changes in your code:

```
date = []
closep = []
for i in range(len(stock_data)):
    temp = stock_data[i].replace(',', ' ').split()
    date.append(temp[0])
    closep.append(temp[2])
```

0 and two are the positions of date and closep in your dataset.

Now instead of 'x' and 'closep' as you have used in your plot method, use these 'date ' and 'closep' I just shared you via code.

One more thing is that the graph is having trouble with this big dataset I think.
So use date[0:100], closep[0:100] to try the plot for smaller dataset.

The complete code would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime


def graph_data():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

    stock_price_url = 
   'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')

    for line in split_source[1:]:
        stock_data.append(line)

    date = []
    closep = []
    for i in range(len(stock_data)):
        temp = stock_data[i].replace(',', ' ').split()
        date.append(temp[0])
        closep.append(temp[2])

    ax1.plot_date(date[0:100], closep[0:100], '-', linewidth=0.1)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Graph')
    plt.show()


graph_data()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How did this remove my error, could you elaborate how changing comma to a space will make any difference ? We are anyways splitting at the comma point

Comment: Your dataset has following format :data = '2017-07-26,153.3500,153.9300,153.0600,153.5000,153.5000,12778195.00'. So, your data has strings inside a list. So I iterated over the dataset and for every string first, I replaced commas with space and then used split method to create a list of strings for every string which has values from date to volume. What split does is it returns every word separated by space in a string into a list. Now I selected date and closep from every list of the dataset and appended them into a separate list. Now use data and closep to create your plot.

Comment: Please look into replace and split methods then you will be able to understand easily.